# Spring boot I keep getting an error when logging in and I can't login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to create a username and login in my project.
I can create username but,
I cannot login to the system with the username I created.

I'm trying to login in my application with spring security, but it gives me an error. Also, I'm storing my password in data base in bcrypted form. In associate table I have got userid and roleid. But I can't login. What I've missed? User table in mysql

I couldn't solve this problem, can you help me please?

```
Default;
username=admin
password=admin
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj3zT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxgy.png)

Here is my  **User Repository**

```
public interface IUserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);
```

Here is my **USER SERVİCE**

```
Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);

void save(User user);


void autoLogin(HttpServletRequest request, String username, String password);
```

Here is my **UserserviceImpl**

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

@Autowired
private IUserRepository iuserRepository;

@Autowired
private IRoleRepository iRoleRepository;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username) {
    return iuserRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
}

@Override
public void save(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setActive(true);
    Role userRole = iRoleRepository.findRoleByName("ROLE_USER");
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
    iuserRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public void autoLogin(HttpServletRequest request, String username, String password) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

Here is my **Login Page**

```
  <form th:action="@{/login}"  method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Username</label>
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Username">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my **Controller**
public class UserRegistrationController {

```
@Autowired
private IUserService iUserService;

@Autowired
private IAnimalOwnersService iAnimalOwnersService;

@Autowired
private IAnimalsService iAnimalsService;

@ModelAttribute("user")
public User user() {
    return new User();
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String indexPage() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/index")
public String indexPage2() {
    return "index";
}
@GetMapping("/register")
public String registerShowPage() {
    return "register";
}
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model theModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    String username = user.getUsername();
    String password = user.getPassword();

    Optional<User> optionalUser = (iUserService.findUserByUsername(username));
    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        theModel.addAttribute("alreadyExistsUser", "Username is used");
        return "register";

    }

    iUserService.save(user);
    iUserService.autoLogin(httpServletRequest, username, password);
    List<String> userRoleNames = 
    user.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("username", username);
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String dashboardPage(Model theModel) {

    Long totalOwners = iAnimalOwnersService.totalUsers();
    Long totanAnimals = iAnimalsService.totalAnimals();

    theModel.addAttribute("totalOwners", totalOwners);
    theModel.addAttribute("totanAnimals", totanAnimals);

    return "dashboard";
}

@GetMapping({"/login", "/login.html"})
public String loginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

Here is my **Configuration**

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private final String USERS_QUERY = "select username, password, active from user where username=?";
private final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.username, r.name from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.username=?";

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers()
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/login", "/index", "/")
            .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?loginFailed=true")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard.html", true)
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/index");

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Comment: I guess the only thing missing now, is the error you get (stacktrace). BR

Comment: as a developer we read logs and error messages. The error messages tell us whats wrong. Writing `but it gives me an error.` does not say anything about what KIND of error you are getting, and how we can be able to fix it.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors it just doesn't log in https://ibb.co/Jnbn1KL

Comment: did you even enable debug logs?

Comment: yes sir i tried  
I can give you the github link if you want.

Comment: @Emre You're in the best position to debug this app, unless you have the patience to wait for a person in here that is willing to set up your env. First, verify that nothing is missing from db-tables. You don't show us the role table. Then find out exactly where the login fails by adding breakpoints in your code, and then run app in debug mode. Putting a whole app together without unit tests, often results in a situation where debugging is required, in various degree. Good luck! BR

Comment: @EmreKürşat i dont want a Github link, i want you to post the full debug logs of when you are logging in. The full logs, so that we can see everything that happens. Also in the future, you should ALWAYS post your full debug logs in EVERY question when you are asking the question. We should not need to have to ask for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error, thank you.
@Toerktumlar
@Roar S.

Adding a name to the form was enough.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label >Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="username"  class="form-control" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Username">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password"  class="form-control" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
</div>



<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```